# jQuery Autocomplete remote datasource and dynamic rows

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, sql-server, autocomplete

I have an idea to do this :

[image: Requisition]

- **Search** textbox will do the autocomplete action and it will display the result on `textbox 1` , `textbox 2`, `textbox 3` and user
  will enter the Quantity that they want on `textbox 4`.
- Supposed after searching for an Item, the user must press the `ADD` button and automatically the page will generate a row without reloading the page. So when the user chose the second item that they desire, the page will generate a second row below the first ones.
- To finish the process, the user will have to press the `SUBMIT` button and then the data will be inserted into the database.

**I managed to do the autocomplete :**

```
<script>
      $(function() {
        function log( message ) {
          $( "<div>" ).text( message ).prependTo( "#log" );
          $( "#log" ).scrollTop( 0 );
        }

        $( "#ItemName" ).autocomplete({
          source: "requisition_search.php",
          minLength: 1,
          select: function( event, ui ) 
              {
                  $('#ItmId').val(ui.item.id);
                  $('#ItmName').val(ui.item.value);
                  $('#ItmUOM').val(ui.item.uom);
                  $('#ItmQty').val(ui.item.qty);
              }

        });
      });
    </script>
```

But i have no idea how to do the dynamic rows. I know some uses `JS` or `jQuery` but i am very new to both of em. I've found some examples that generate codes and implement the autocomplete on the dynamically rows. But i want it to be generated `after` the user enters the data and by the clicking the button `ADD`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like below.

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
    <title>jQuery Dynamic Rows</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script>
    $(document).ready(function(){

        $("#add").on("click",function(){

          var rowcount = $("#rowcount").val();
          var row = '<tr id="'+rowcount+'"><td>'+$("#itemid").val()+'</td><td>'+$("#itemname").val()+'</td><td>'+$("#uom").val()+'</td><td>'+$("#quantity").val()+'</td></tr>'; 

           rowcount = parseInt(rowcount)+1;

           $("#rowcount").val(rowcount);
           $("#dataTab").append(row);
           $("#dataTab").show();
           $("#submit").show();            

        });

    });

</script>
    </head>

    <body>


     <form name="jqtest" action="#">

       Item ID : <input type="text" name="itemid" id="itemid"/><br/><br/>
       Item name : <input type="text" name="itemname" id="itemname"/><br/><br/>
       UOM : <input type="text" name="uom" id="uom"/><br/><br/>
       Quantity : <input type="text" name="quantity" id="quantity"/><br/><br/>

       <p> <input type="reset" name="reset" id="reset" value="RESET"/>&nbsp;&nbsp;<input type="button" name="add" id="add" value="ADD"/> </p>
        <input type="hidden" name="rowcount" id="rowcount" value="1"/>
     </form>

     <table id="dataTab" style="display:none;" border="1">

      <tr>
        <th>Item ID</th>
        <th>Item name</th>
        <th>UOM</th>
        <th>Quantity</th>
      </tr>

     </table>

    <p> <input style="display:none;" type="button" name="submit" id="submit" value="submit"/> </p>

    </body>

    </html>
```

Comment: Thanks! This worked! But i have an issue to save the data into the database. Could you take a look at this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26965111/how-to-insert-values-from-dynamically-added-rows-into-database

Comment: @AthirahHazira I've answered. Please see solution. Sorry for the delay!