# How to insert values from dynamically added rows into database

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, sql-server, autocomplete

***I've been stuck on this for days. I really appreciate your help.***

- I'm working on a php form that generates dynamically added rows when
  the user click the button `ADD`.
- To save the values into the database, users must click the `SUBMIT`
  button.
- The problem that i'm facing is that the database doesn't save the
  values from the dynamic rows.

**AUTOCOMPLETE & DYNAMIC ROWS**

```
<script>
//autocomplete
  $(function() {
    function log( message ) {
      $( "<div>" ).text( message ).prependTo( "#log" );
      $( "#log" ).scrollTop( 0 );
    }

    $( "#ItemName" ).autocomplete({
      source: "user/requisition_search.php",
      minLength: 1,
      select: function( event, ui ) 
          {
              $('#ItmId').val(ui.item.id);
              $('#StkId').val(ui.item.stkId);
              $('#ItmNameDis').val(ui.item.value);
              $('#ItmUOM').val(ui.item.uom);
              $('#ItmQty').val(ui.item.qty);

          }

    });
  });
//dynamic rows
    $(document).ready(function(){

        $("#add").on("click",function(){

          var rowcount = $("#rowcount").val();
          var row = 
          '<tr id="'+rowcount+'"><td>'+$("#ItmId").val()+'</td><td><input readonly="readonly" name="StkId[]" value="'+$("#StkId").val()+'"/></td><td>'+$("#ItemName").val()+'</td><td>'+$("#ItmUOM").val()+'</td><td>'+$("#ItmQty").val()+'</td><td><input readonly="readonly" name="ReqQty[]" value="'+$("#ReqQty").val()+'"/></td></tr>';

           rowcount = parseInt(rowcount)+1;

           $("#rowcount").val(rowcount);
           $("#dataTab").append(row);
           $("#dataTab").show();
           $("#submit").show();           

        });

    });
</script>
```

**HTML**

```
<form name="jqtest" action="submit.php" method="post">
<label for="ItemName">Search : </label>
<input id="ItemName" size="50"/>

<label for="ItmId">Item Id </label>
<input name="ItmId" id="ItmId" readonly="readonly"/>

<label for="StkId">Stock Id </label></td>
<input name="StkId" id="StkId" readonly="readonly"/>

<label for="ItmNameDis">Item Name </label>
<input name="ItmNameDis" id="ItmNameDis" size="50" readonly="readonly"/></td>

<label for="ItmUOM">Unit Of Measurement </label>
<input name="ItmUOM" id="ItmUOM" readonly="readonly"/>

<td><label for="ItmQty">Quantity Available </label>
<input name="ItmQty" id="ItmQty" readonly="readonly"/>

<label for="ReqQty">Quantity </label>
<input name="ReqQty" id="ReqQty" onkeypress="return numbersOnly(event)" onkeyup="ItmQty_Availability()" disabled="disabled"/>

      <p>
        <input type="reset" name="reset" id="reset" value="RESET"/>
        &nbsp;&nbsp;
        <input type="button" name="add" id="add" value="ADD"/>
      </p>

      <input type="hidden" name="rowcount" id="rowcount" value="1"/>

<table id="dataTab" width="90%" style="display:none;" border="1" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
        <tr>
          <th>Item ID</th>
          <th>Stock ID</th>
          <th>Item name</th>
          <th>UOM</th>
          <th>Quantity Available</th>
          <th>Quantity Requested</th>
        </tr>
      </table>
      <p>&nbsp;</p>
      <p><input style="display:none;" type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" value="SUBMIT"/></p>
    </form>
```

**submit.php**

```
<?php

$num =  $_POST['rowcount'];
for($i=0;$i<$num;$i++)
{

      $strStkId = "";
      if(!empty($_POST)){
          if(isset($_POST["StkId[]"])){
              $strStkId = $_POST["StkId[]"];
          }else{
               echo "<font color=red>Enter the Stock Id</br></font>";
          }

      }
      $strReqQty = "";
      if(!empty($_POST)){
          if(isset($_POST["ReqQty[]"])){
              $strReqQty = $_POST["ReqQty[]"];
          }else{
               echo "<font color=red>Enter the Quantity</font>";
          }

      }

        $tsql =
        "INSERT INTO REQUISITION
        (RequestQuantity, StockId)
        VALUES
        ('$strReqQty','$strStkId')
        ";

        $result = sqlsrv_query($conn, $tsql, array(), array( "Scrollable" => SQLSRV_CURSOR_KEYSET ));   

            if (!$result) {
            die ('<script>
                window.alert("Please enter the requisition details !")
                window.location.href = "requisition.php"; </script>');
            }
            else 
            echo '<script>alert("Your Requisition is In Process"); </script>';
            sqlsrv_close($conn);
}
?>
```

**UPDATED**

I've learnt that `name="StkId"` and `name="StkId[]"` clashes in the dynamic rows and the inputs. 
So i've change into something like this :

```
var row = '<tr id="'+rowcount+'"><td>'+$("#ItmId").val()+'</td><td><input readonly="readonly" name="StkId2" value="'+$("#StkId").val()+'"/></td><td>'+$("#ItemName").val()+'</td><td>'+$("#ItmUOM").val()+'</td><td>'+$("#ItmQty").val()+'</td><td><input readonly="readonly" name="ReqQty2" value="'+$("#ReqQty").val()+'"/></td></tr>';
```

Now the data are inserted into the database but `IF` the user enters `more than one` item, only `one` data is inserted into the database. What did i do wrong? I guess its at the `submit.php` part but i can't figure out why.

Comment: FYI: when you have have attributes such as `name="stkId[]"`. You don't need to call it as is in the post index. Just use `$_POST['stkId']`. that already returns an array

Comment: @Ghost But i want the values from the dynamic rows? This :
`<td><input readonly="readonly" name="StkId[]" value="'+$("#StkId").val()+'"/></td>` and `<td><input readonly="readonly" name="ReqQty[]" value="'+$("#ReqQty").val()+'"/></td>`

Comment: Just call it as `$_POST['stkId']`. no need for that `[]`

Comment: @Ghost it doesn't work still

Comment: @Ghost like this. From the dynamic rows : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26955139/jquery-autocomplete-remote-datasource-and-dynamic-rows

Comment: anyways, the initial input set must already have `name=""stkId[]`. start it already with that. then, use classes instead. `id=""` values are supposed to be unique

Comment: @Ghost but if i set the names as `name="StkId[]"` the same as the dynamic rows name, then they only read from the input sets. Not the dynamic rows.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You won't get dynamically generated row values in `$_POST` on submitting the form because those are not at all form inputs but just displaying as row in a table. But you can achieve your functionality with the help of jQuery AJAX. On clicking the submit button, calls your `submit.php` using AJAX. The sample solution for how to retrieve values of those dynamically rows is given below. You can adapt this method for your requirement.

Main Page.

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
    <title>jQuery Dynamic Rows</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script>
    $(document).ready(function(){

        $("#add").on("click",function(){

          var rowcount = $("#rowcount").val();
          var row = '<tr class="dynamic" id="'+rowcount+'"><td>'+$("#itemid").val()+'</td><td>'+$("#itemname").val()+'</td><td>'+$("#uom").val()+'</td><td>'+$("#quantity").val()+'</td></tr>'; 

           rowcount = parseInt(rowcount)+1;

           $("#rowcount").val(rowcount);
           $("#dataTab").append(row);
           $("#dataTab").show();
           $("#submit").show();            

        });

        $("#submit").on("click",function(){
                alert("submit");
                var jsonObj = [];
                i=0;
            $("#dataTab tr.dynamic").each(function(){

               var td = $(this).find('td');

                itemId = td.eq(0).text();
                itemName = td.eq(1).text();
                uom = td.eq(2).text();
                quantity = td.eq(3).text();

                jsonObj.push({
                    itemId: itemId,
                    itemName: itemName,
                    uom: uom,
                    quantity: quantity,
                });
            });

            var dataString = JSON.stringify(jsonObj);


                $.ajax({
                    url: "submit.php",
                    type: "POST",
                    data: {json:dataString},
                    success: function(response){
                               alert(response);
                             }
                });

        });

    });

</script>
    </head>

    <body>


     <form name="jqtest" action="#">

       Item ID : <input type="text" name="itemid" id="itemid"/><br/><br/>
       Item name : <input type="text" name="itemname" id="itemname"/><br/><br/>
       UOM : <input type="text" name="uom" id="uom"/><br/><br/>
       Quantity : <input type="text" name="quantity" id="quantity"/><br/><br/>

       <p> <input type="reset" name="reset" id="reset" value="RESET"/>&nbsp;&nbsp;<input type="button" name="add" id="add" value="ADD"/> </p>
        <input type="hidden" name="rowcount" id="rowcount" value="1"/>
     </form>

     <table id="dataTab" style="display:none;" border="1">

      <tr>
        <th>Item ID</th>
        <th>Item name</th>
        <th>UOM</th>
        <th>Quantity</th>
      </tr>

     </table>

    <p> <input style="display:none;" type="button" name="submit" id="submit" value="submit"/> </p>

    </body>

    </html>
```

submit.php

```
<?php

  $arr = json_decode($_POST['json']);


  for($i=0; $i<count($arr); $i++)
   {
     echo "Row ".$i."\n";
     echo "itemId > ".$arr[$i]->itemId.", itemName > ".$arr[$i]->itemName.", uom > ".$arr[$i]->uom.", quantity > ".$arr[$i]->quantity."\n";

   }

?>
```

Comment: can you explain this part since i'm just a beginner and have no basic on ajax and json :
`$("#dataTab tr.dynamic").each(function(){

               var td = $(this).find('td');

                itemId = td.eq(0).text();
                itemName = td.eq(1).text();
                uom = td.eq(2).text();
                quantity = td.eq(3).text();

                jsonObj.push({
                    itemId: itemId,
                    itemName: itemName,
                    uom: uom,
                    quantity: quantity,
                });
            });`

Comment: and on submit.php, to insert the values into the database, in the loop, i have to code as usual?? cuz the codes that u gave just echoes into the alert box but it retrieves the data. So i would love it if u explain to me on the submit.php and on the code i comment above. I'm sorry i don't have any basic on ajax and json.

Comment: Nevermind. I've got it. I mean insert the data into the database. Thank you! You literally saved me :)

Comment: lol sorry but i'm curious tho. Is there any way that all this can be achieved just by using jQuery, javascript and php ?

Comment: @AthirahHazira `$("#dataTab tr.dynamic").each(function()..` this part actually get all `tr` with class name dynamic & get corresponding `td` values (that eq(0), eq(1) etc. help to get itemId, itemName etc.) & all those values added into a javascript object in loop. this Qn "Is there any way that all this can be achieved just by using jQuery, javascript and php ?". Yes. Of course. Since You're a beginner, It takes some time 2 clear all but the stuffs you're doing is not just basic. I really appreciate cuz I had no idea to write even single HTML line of code when I was @ your age! Cheers..:)

Comment: Thanks Jeson. I understand now. But im curious. If i were to submit the data into the database then display the arrays in an `html/php` page, how can i achieve that? I mean if i just echoes the output, they only display in alert boxes. What if i wanna submit on `submit.php` then `display` on a `page or popup page` of the `arrays submitted` just now? I really appreciate your help

Comment: @AthirahHazira You Can do. Alert I had included just to demonstrate how AJAx Response coming back from the server. In Server, You can insert data into MySQL in the normal method. Anyway, Mail all things what you've tried to jenson555[at]gmail[dot]com